# Error in receiving data from server

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I want to make my test function below print out the message "k isn't nil" but my code doesn't work. It has already received k value from my server but it doesn't check the line if k~=nil then. Below is my code. Thanks for any incoming advice.

```
local function receiveData(  )
    local l,e = client:receive()
    if l~=nil then
        print(l)
        return l,e
    else
        timer.performWithDelay(100,receiveData)
    end
end

function test( )
    k = receiveData()
    if k ~=nil then
        print("k isn't nil")
    end
end

test()
```

Comment: Would appreciate a comment if you think answer should be improved to get up vote, thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that if the data is not received on the first try then k is nil and test returns. The `receiveData` will be called again at 100 millisecond intervals until data is received, but the return is discarded by performWithDelay and by then `test` has returned (see first sentence of this answer).

The solution is to set a callback that `receiveData` can call when the data eventually arrives. The callback can then process the data. Replace `return l,e` by `onReceiveData(l,e)` and have that do something that test waits for in a `while` loop. Of course `receiveData` could directly set this flag being watched by test but once your app gets larger it is a good idea to separate receive from process.

```
function receiveData() 
...
-- then:

local data = nil

function onReceiveData(l,e)
    data = l
    print('ready to process data', data, e)
end

funtion test() 
    receiveData() 
    while data == nil do sleep(100) end 
    print('data received and processed') 
end

test()
```

where `sleep(100)` is what you can come up with  since there is no builtin function that does that in Lua or even Corona (although Corona has `system.getTimer()` which returns ms since app start, so you could have

```
function sleep(ms) 
    local start = system.getTimer() 
    while system.getTimer() - start < ms do 
    end
end
```

I'm not too keen on the empty while loop but in a test utility function it is OK. If you are using the socket library it has a sleep function -- check out the [Lua wiki](http://lua-users.org/wiki/SleepFunction) for other options).

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you received the data? What does your program print in the console?

You may consider the following modification

```
local function receiveData(  )
  local l,e = client:receive()
  if l~=nil then
    print(l)
    return l,e
  else
    timer.performWithDelay(100,function() l, e = receiveData() end)
  end
  return l, e
end
```

So my guess is, that when receiveData gets called second time, your return values (l, e) are discarded (because performWithDelay doesn't do anything with them).

Comment: Hi vetham, I'm sure that the data was received because it print value which I sent correctly but don't know why it doesn't print in test() function.

Comment: Did you try my modifications?

Comment: Hi vetham, I've tried writing new function in my test function by letting k = client:receive() and it works. Also don't understand why the code above doesn't work.